# Removing spaces from a input form string with JavaScript and PHP?

Tags: javascript, laravel

[image: Removing spaces in a string]

Considering this input form, how do you remove the spaces on copy and paste into the form?

How do you remove spaces from the request when passing this value to the database?

Comment: `'12 34 56 78'.replace(/ /g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var activities = document.getElementById("fieldname");
    
activities.addEventListener("change", function() {
  value = activities.value;
  value = value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  activities.value = value;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" id="fieldname">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not enough jQuery.

Comment: @JavaScript what should I add more in it?

Comment: You should refrain from using jQuery if the question is not tagged as such.

Comment: @JavaScript pls check the js version of answer and remove the downvote pls.

Comment: You example is actually pretty bad.. change event on input.text, outside defined elements and undefined variables.. Please provide a running snippet or just remove it.